# What is the best practice to pass data to components in Angular?

Tags: angular

Can we pass the entire parent component data(this) to child component by @input in angular4 ?
It's Working. But my doubt is Can I do this or It's bad design?

## Parent

```
    export class SchedulerComponent implements OnInit {

      public parent: SchedulerComponent = this;

    <div class="row">
        <app-scheduler-result *ngIf="resultData" [(_parent)]="parent">
        </app-scheduler-result>
    </div>
```

## Child

```
export class SchedulerResultComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input('_parent') result;
```

OR - Below method can follow ?

```
 class Child{
  name:string; 
  dd:string; 
  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => Parent)) app:Parent)
  { this.name = app.getName(); this.dd= app.data; console.log(this.name); }

 }
```

Please advise.
Thank you

Comment: It is a bad practice... You should pass the properties you need directly instead of this. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: Thank you Alex for quick response

Comment: If you want to give a value or object back to the parent use **@Output** read https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: you could, but you would be creating a circular dependency (up to some level), where the child depends of the parent and the parent of the child

Comment: You should either expose only properties you need, or create a dedicated service with a Subject variable that has properties you need and subscribe to it.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo that's called a **two-way data binding**. https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview

Comment: @Swoox I wasnt talking about the bindings, but the component hierarchy itself....

Comment: @Jota.Toledo sorry that's how I read it. Thought you commented on me :P

Comment: Thank you all for response. Please tell me about below method for get the parent component variable @AlexBeugnet
/***********/

class Child{ name:string; dd:string; constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => Parent)) app:Parent) { this.name = app.getName(); this.dd= app.data; console.log(this.name); }